# No idea why I keep getting run time error on this problem that works fine to me

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, debugging, runtime-error

I am working on this problem on kattis : https://open.kattis.com/contests/oxfcar/problems/babelfish
I tested it with the input provided and it works fine but I submit on Kattis, I keep getting "RUN TIME ERROR!"
What is the mistake here? I don't understand at all.

```
//  build the dictionary by mapping foreign words to english

line="a"
dict1={}
while True:
  line=input() 
  if not line:
    break
  line=line.split(" ")
  eng=line[0]
  foreign=line[1]
  dict1[foreign]=eng 

newline=""
toPrint=""
while 1==1:
  newline=input()
  if not newline:
    break
  found=False;
  toPrint= toPrint + dict1.get(newline, 'eh') + "\n"

print (toPrint[:-1])
```

Comment: basically to check whether the messages are in the dictionary or not. the user is now gonna start to enter the messages, and we check whether they are in the dictionary that was created in the first part or not. If so, we translate the word. If not, we add the "eh" word. The program runs fine with the testcase that was provided.

Comment: I guess your code is too slow to finish in the permitted time

Comment: Sorry for deleting my previous comment, I just checked the link you posted. I tried your code and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: does it submit also?

Comment: I am having submission issues - run time error

Comment: If you switch the way that you store words in the dict, it will make the lookup phase much easier and simpler. It might help, but not sure it can solve the runtime problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too slow.

The reason why is because you're looping over the whole dictionary to find an element. This defeats the purpose of a dictionary that should have a `O(1)` access to the keys.

Instead of:

```
for x in dict1:
    if dict1[x]==newline:
          toPrint= toPrint + str(x) + "\n"
          found=True
   if found==False:
          toPrint= toPrint + "eh\n"
```

Build a dictionary that has the foreign word as key:

```
dict1[foreign]=eng
```

Then, simply use the `get` method with a default parameter:

```
toPrint= toPrint + dict1.get(newline, 'eh') + "\n"
```

Comment: However, here if the word is not in the dictionary, then it is not working.

Comment: I dont know why I am always getting "eh", even if the foreign word does exist.

Comment: Know that we want the key of the value, not the value itself.

Comment: What does newline contain? How do you handle the `\n` characters? You must have other errors elsewhere ;)

Comment: No, newline is the value of the dictionary. We want its KEY. and the get function just returns the value of a key, not the key of a value.

Comment: Build you dict the other way around. It's nonsense to use the English word as key if you want to translate foreign to English ;)

Comment: I just did all of that but I dont know why I still get run time error.

Comment: I have just updated my code!

Comment: There are still many things to improve. For example `toPrint= toPrint + ...`. Repeated string concatenation is slow. Rather append each item in a list and `join` at the end.

Comment: Well, if the time limit exceeded, then it would clearly say "TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED". But in this case, I keep getting a run time error.

Comment: Have you tested the code yourself on a simple example? Have you debugged the variables?

Comment: Yes, everything. The test case also works perfectly. Everything works.